# Moving column to new row based on screen size html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a three column table in HTML. The cells in the third column are all of the same class.

I want the third column in each row to move to a new row under the column if the screen width is less than 750px.

So, the table would normally look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="thirdcol"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="thirdcol"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

If the screen width is less than 750px, I want the javascript function to make the table look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="thirdcol"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="thirdcol"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? If you show your existing JavaScript code we can help with the part you're stuck on. (Or are you asking us to write the whole thing for you?) Also, is your requirement "move the third column", or "move the column with class='thircol'", or "move the third column only if class='thirdcol'"?

Comment: This is where using DIVs to display columnar data really shines, if you don't have to use tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMzfr/) with a working version of it (using JQuery). Here's the meaty part that actually does the work:

```
if ($(window).width() < 750) {
    $('td.thirdcol').each(function(i, item) {
        var row = $(item).clone(true).prop('colspan','2').wrapAll('<tr />');
        $(item).closest('tr').after(row);
        $(item).remove();
    });
}
```

However, if I were you, I wouldn't use Javascript or tables for this and would use CSS and floating `div`s instead. It's exactly the sort of thing they are designed for.

Comment: This code worked perfectly. Thank you so much. One last request. Is there code that could do the opposite of this, so that I can revert the page back without reloading it?

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's a "plain" JavaScript way of doing it. There's no magical "select the whole column" mechanism (that I'm aware of), so you have to do it row by row, inserting new rows as you go.

```
var t = document.getElementById("table1"),
    r,
    i;
if (screen.width < 750)
    for(i = t.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        r = t.insertRow(i+1);
        r.appendChild(t.rows[i].cells[2]);
    }
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly remove each cell, because [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) will *move* existing elements.

My code assumes you can give your table an ID of "table1", and as you can see it is hard-coded to move the third column - but of course you could wrap it all up in a pretty function with parameters for the table and which column(s) should be moved: that's up to you...